# How to pass as parameter a function that has parameters defined by default without passing them? C++

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
void foo(int Var1, int Var2, int default1=10, int defaul2=10);
void bar(int Var1, int Var2);
someFunction(void (*foobar)(int, int));
otherFunction(void (*foobar)(int, int, int, int));

int main(){
    someFunction(foo); //ERROR
    otherFunction(bar); //ERROR
}
```

So, i want to choose between foo and bar on the same function ignoring the default parameters, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: The error messages you see should tell you what the problem is. If we could see them we could help you read them.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because foo's function signature doesn't correspond to what someFunction expects. The default parameters in foo don't make the parameters go away, it just fills it with a default value at compile time.

You could try casting foo and see what that gives you.

```
typedef void (*twoParameterFunctionType)(int, int);

someFunction((twoParamterFunctionType)foo);
```

Comment: `You could try casting foo and see what that gives you`. It gives you UB if `foobar` is ever called. And the only reason you would ever pass a function pointer is to call it eventually, so it gives you UB